# Codeception/Selenium: Is it possible to make a Scenario with variable names?

Tags: php, selenium, codeception

I have a Codeception Test:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Search for Germany');
$I->amOnPage('http://www.google.com');
$I->fillField('#lst-ib', 'Germany');
$I->makeScreenshot('screen');
```

When I make the Command  `php codecept.phar generate:scenarios` this creates a "readable" format for non-developers.

```
.....
I fill Field '#lst-ib', 'Germany'
....
```

But is it possible to put for example the input field with the id=lst-ib in a variable? For example:

```
$googleInputField = '#lst-ib';
```

And when I then call the "generate:scenarios" action, the Text shoud be:

```
.....
I fill Field 'googleInputField', 'Germany'
....
```

Comment: No, it is impossible. How about filling field by name? $I->fillField('q', 'Germany');

Comment: No, I want that a "non-devoloper" can read it. So when there is standing: "I fill Field q" ....thats not good

Comment: Give better names to your input fields.